# How to call JBoss's Drools as a remote rules executor

Tags: java, jboss, drools

what I want to do is use java and Drools for its nice rule engine capabilities. Currently I am not using java for my project. I have some implementation business classes and implemented logics that works fine for me, but I want to externalize the rules in BRMS. I gave Drools a try and I like it a lot. However I encounter one obsticle that I want to ask if I can skip.

I read most of the Drools documentation and across the net in all the examples that are given we actually need the implementation business classes in order to instantiate facts that we want to feed to the Drools *KieSession*. Well what I want is not to duplicate my class model in both my (non java) project and my java Drools project. All I want to keep in my Drools project is the Rules themselves.

So is that possible, or I will need to duplicate the models?
If anyone knows where I can read some info on that topic links are appriciated!

Technical details:
I am using Drools 6.0.0 in Eclipse Juno.

Big thanks for the support!

Best Regards!
Milen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A convenient way to bridge the gap would be to create an XML Schema defining types for what you have now. Perhaps there's a simple way of converting the objects of your current language into XML. Given the XML Schema and the XML data, you can automatically generate Java classes from the Schema and then unmarshal the XML and insert the resulting Java object.

You can't run rules without data.

Comment: By generating the Java classes from XML you mean using EMF and Ecore right?

Comment: I did some research and indeed this is the best solution. The business class model is needed inside the Drools project to instantiate facts!. Thanks Laune.

Comment: JAXB's xjc to compile an XML schema into Java classes works fine for me, but YMMV. XML Schema must be toned down some to deliver good Java classes.